# Simple blender OpenGL Triangle vertex position corruption

Tags: python, blender, pyopengl

Trying to learn to draw in blender viewport using bgl. However no matter what vertex positions I pass to the bgl.Buffer and thus to the vertex shader, I get only one vertex in the bottom left corner of the viewport.

I've tried hardcoding the vertex positions in the vertex shader, Then I get my triangle.But as soon as I change the hardcoded positions to `layout(location = 0)in vec3 vPos;`, and pass the data via the VBO, I don't get the same result.

```
import bpy
import numpy as np
from bgl import *

draw_handler = None

print(f'{" Program Compile Start ":=^40}')
vertex_shader_source = """
#version 330

layout(location = 0) in vec3 vPos;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(vPos.xy,0,1);
}
"""
fragment_shader_source = """
#version 330

out vec4 FragColor;

void main()
{
    FragColor = vec4(0,1,0,1);
}
"""
statusVert = Buffer(GL_INT, [1])
statusFrag = Buffer(GL_INT, [1])
statusProgram = Buffer(GL_INT, [1])
program    = glCreateProgram()
shaderVert = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
shaderFrag = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)

glShaderSource(shaderVert,vertex_shader_source)
glShaderSource(shaderFrag,fragment_shader_source)

glCompileShader(shaderVert)
glCompileShader(shaderFrag)
glGetShaderiv(shaderVert,GL_COMPILE_STATUS,statusVert)
glGetShaderiv(shaderFrag,GL_COMPILE_STATUS,statusFrag)

if   statusVert[0] == GL_TRUE   : print('Vertex Shader compilation successfull')
if statusFrag[0]   == GL_TRUE   : print('Fragment Shader compilation successfull')
if statusVert[0]   == GL_FALSE  : print('Vertex Shader compilation failed')
if statusFrag[0]   == GL_FALSE  : print('Fragment Shader compilation failed')


glAttachShader(program,shaderVert)
glAttachShader(program,shaderFrag)
glLinkProgram(program)

glGetProgramiv(program, GL_LINK_STATUS, statusProgram)
if   statusProgram[0] == GL_TRUE  : print('Program Linking Successfull')
elif statusProgram[0] == GL_FALSE : print('Program Linking Failed')
else: print('Program Linking unknown')
print(f'{" Program Compile end ":=^40}')

# Data

vertex_pos = [-0.5,-0.5, 0,
               0.5,-0.5, 0,
               0.0, 0.5, 0]
vertex_pos = np.array(vertex_pos,dtype=np.float64)
print(vertex_pos.itemsize)
vertex_buff = Buffer(GL_DOUBLE,[9],vertex_pos)
vertex_buff_size = len(vertex_pos)*8
print(vertex_buff_size)
print(vertex_buff)

VAO,VBO = Buffer(GL_INT,1),Buffer(GL_INT,1)
glGenVertexArrays(1,VAO)
glGenBuffers(1,VBO)
print(f'VAO:{VAO[0]} || VBO:{VBO[0]}')

glBindVertexArray(VAO[0])
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,VBO[0])
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 9*8,vertex_buff,GL_STATIC_DRAW)

glEnableVertexAttribArray(0)
glVertexAttribPointer(0,3,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,3*8,0)

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,0)
glBindVertexArray(0)

def draw():
    glUseProgram(program)
    glBindVertexArray(VAO[0])

    glPointSize(30)
    glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS,0,3)

    glBindVertexArray(0)
    glUseProgram(0)



draw_handler = bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(draw, (), 'WINDOW', 'POST_PIXEL')
def in_5_seconds():
    print(f'{" Ending ":=^40}')
    glDeleteBuffers(1,VBO)
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1,VAO)
    glDeleteShader(shaderVert)
    glDeleteShader(shaderFrag)
    glDeleteProgram(program)
    bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_remove(draw_handler,'WINDOW')
bpy.app.timers.register(in_5_seconds, first_interval=5)
```

If I use pyOpenGL wrapper with GLFW. I would get a triangle or in my case the points of one.Yet the blender wrapper renders only one point.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was that blender uses many contexts to draw various bits of the UI.
Programs, shaders, VBO and others are shared among contexts. But VAOs are not.
So you have to create it in the draw loop.

In the end I solved it with a simple `switch` inside the draw function that is passed to the View3D handler: if it's first run you run your init stage, if not, then go on drawing.